# How to get current system locale name?

Tags: winapi, mfc

My default operating system is English. I have changed system locale name to Japanese.
How can I get the current system locale name(Japanese).
Please find the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

I had tried the below api's to get the system locale, but none of them are worked for me. For instance as per above scenario I must get system locale name as Japanese.

```
-GetLocaleInfo
-GetUserDefaultLCID
-GetSystemDefaultLangID
```

Answer (score 5):

*Japanese* is not a [locale name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373814.aspx). It's the localized language name. The respective *locale name* would be `ja-JP` for Japanese (Japan).

To retrieve the current user's localized language name, call [GetLocaleInfoEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318103.aspx) specifying an `LCType` parameter of [LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDLANGUAGENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373853.aspx).

Comment: thank you for your reply. By using GetSystemDefaultLangID() I am able to get the locale. Now as I have Japanese locale on English operating system, can I get the on what operating system I am? Api's to get both locale and current operating system language name(are there api's to differentiate between locale and operating system language name Ex:english, Japanese). Kindly help me :)

Comment: @Siva Please concentrate on the question that was asked.  If you want to ask a new and different question, do so.  But not in comments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry for that and Thanks for your suggestion.